# Vaadin:A suitable Design Pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, vaadin

I'm about to start to develop a Vaadin web application, I also plan to use Spring IOC container.

As far was I know it is pretty much like a Swing application, and I see that people use Presentation Model or MVC "like" patterns.

If you have experience on Vaadin can you suggest me a design pattern regrading the structure of Vaadin framework? maybe a slightly modified version of Presentation Model or MVP or MVC whatever? I also read that there are some patterns provided in Vaadin, what are they?

Thanks

Comment: Vaadin is very similar to Swing: view is the UI controls, model is the data to set to controls, controller is your action (or event listener).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to use the MVP pattern, it keeps the code nice and clean and it suites well for Vaadin applications. There are even [multiple MVP add-ons](http://vaadin.com/directory#browse%3asearch=mvp) you could try out.

Comment: they are either experimental ir beta, which one dud u use? And recommend?

Comment: I've used the MVP4Vaadin at least 2-3 times. It's quite stable and haven't found any problems with it.

Comment: hi, I tried to use but there is zero documentation on how to use MVP4Vaadin, do you know any demo app using this addon ?

Comment: Even though I'm quite new to Vaadin the given MVP examples and addons I was able to find on the Internet offer an extremely overbloated piece of software. I cannot imagine (again - given the examples I was able to find) anything larger than a simple calculator a la HelloWorld application done in such a way. The documentation for all these addons is also poor to nonexistent, which makes it even more difficult to use them properly (maybe that's why the examples are of such poor quality?).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try Vaadin together with Grails. Grails gives you clear division between database, services and view layer (+ you will get Spring IoC for free). If you want to give it a try, follow [this one](http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.com/2012/03/vaadin-and-grails-part-i-hello-world.html).

If not, you can

- as view, create UI with components from Vaadin
- you could also use State pattern for implementation of different states of UI screens
- create your implementation of DAO pattern (and put somewhere there also your domain classes)
- and use Listener pattern for action

The second option without Grails is pure Java, but it is also more painful.

Comment: Thanks, how about using only Spring IOC and just separete my view and logic and data classes, no DAO or listener pattern

Comment: Actually, I think that is too heavy weapon for that kind of stuff. I prefer simple and easy to understand solutions (and if possible, no XML configurations...). So I think that Vaadin+Grails might be nice option for you. But it depends on what are you technology constraints...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring and Vaadin together, consider using the [Spring Stuff Vaadin add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/spring-stuff) for application autowiring, etc.

Disclaimer: I'm the author

Comment: Hi Archie, I already used it and finished the project. thank you